# How i assign value of http get to sub array in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, httpresponse

I am trying to push data to sub-array (nested array) the data that comes from the response is good but did not push the value to a subarray but at the end, I got an empty array.

```
for (var j=0;j<this.imagesdataarray.length;j++){
 
    this.http.get("http://api.interiordesigns2020.com/api/services/app/ImageProject/GetAll?ProjectID="+this.imagesdataarray[j].projectid+"&MaxResultCount="+10000).subscribe( (res:any) =>{
    this.data=res;
    for  (var k in this.data.result.items.length){
      this.imagesdataarray[j].imagesnamearray.push({image:this.data.result.items[k].imageFiles,imagename:this.data.result.items[k].imageName,imageid:this.data.result.items[k].id ,completeimagepath:this.globalshare.websiteurl+"/images/UploadedWork/"+this.userid+"/"+this.imagesdataarray[j].projectid+"/"+ this.data.result.items[k].imageName});
  }
  });
}
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Please format your code, so there are no long lines and the indentation is correct. It's quite hard to read and understand like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use forEach to handle async operations:

```js
this.data = [];

this.imagesdataarray.forEach(x => {
  this.http.get("http://api.interiordesigns2020.com/api/services/app/ImageProject/GetAll?ProjectID=" + x.projectid + "&MaxResultCount=" + 10000).subscribe( (res:any) =>{
    this.data.push(res);       
    });
})

console.log(this.data);
```